# React material-UI override default form input style

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to override default form input style, so I've [found](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/text-fields/#customized-inputs) this code below. The problem is that I would like to add `error behaviour` of the form input, but I don't know how. Could anyone help me to add red border to the input when it's in error state? Thank you very much!

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

const styles = theme => ({
  textFieldRoot: {
    padding: 0,
    'label + &': {
      marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    },
  },
  textFieldInput: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    border: '1px solid #ced4da',
    fontSize: 16,
    padding: '10px 12px',
    width: 'calc(100% - 24px)',
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['border-color', 'box-shadow']),
    '&:focus': {
      borderColor: '#80bdff',
      boxShadow: '0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25)',
    },
  },
  textFieldFormLabel: {
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});

function CustomizedInputs(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <TextField
        defaultValue="react-bootstrap"
        label="Bootstrap"
        id="bootstrap-input"
        InputProps={{
          disableUnderline: true,
          classes: {
            root: classes.textFieldRoot,
            input: classes.textFieldInput,
          },
        }}
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true,
          className: classes.textFieldFormLabel,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(CustomizedInputs);
```

Comment: Are you using the beta version of material ui ?

Comment: @HarshMakadia yes :-)

Comment: Check this out here - https://codesandbox.io/s/l9291xn0l. It seems to work.

Comment: @HarshMakadia but it's default material ui input look ... it doesn't work for the edited one, which looks more like bootstrap input

Comment: Are you trying to do this application-wide? If so, what you want is something more like this - https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#customizing-all-instances-of-a-component-type

This gives you access to all of the states of the control. You can look at the source code for a given control and see how it's calculating its styles and then override it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could approach this a few ways possibly using a `regex`, also Redux has a `validate` attribute but this example uses `onChange` to run a check function that sets a boolean if there is an error. Then that boolean determines which class name the input will pick up.

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

const styles = theme => ({
  textFieldRoot: {
    padding: 0,
    'label + &': {
      marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    },
  },
  textFieldError: {
    border: '1px solid red',
  },
  textFieldInput: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    border: '1px solid #ced4da',
    fontSize: 16,
    padding: '10px 12px',
    width: 'calc(100% - 24px)',
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['border-color', 'box-shadow']),
    '&:focus': {
      borderColor: '#80bdff',
      boxShadow: '0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25)',
    },
  },
  textFieldFormLabel: {
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});

function CustomizedInputs(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  const checkField = () => {
    // some condition to check for error
    errorVariable = true
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <TextField
        defaultValue="react-bootstrap"
        label="Bootstrap"
        id="bootstrap-input"
        onChange={checkField}
        InputProps={{
          disableUnderline: true,
          classes: {
            root: classes.textFieldRoot,
            input: errorVariable ? classes.textFieldError : classes.textFieldInput,
          },
        }}
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true,
          className: classes.textFieldFormLabel,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(CustomizedInputs);
```